# Not a definitive regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am still learning `Regex` so help me out if I am wrong somewhere. In my project I am using simple formatted string to create a `RichTextBlock` through `XAML Reader`. I am able to format my string through some `Regex` patterns and now there is a problem that sometimes a `<Hyperlink />` gets left out of the `<Paragraph>` tags and it throws exception.

The sample `string` for this is:

```
</Paragraph> some words here (@somevaluehere1)
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://somelink.com">July 14, 2017</Hyperlink>
```

I want a `Regex` pattern to look out for this match:

> if the opening TAG of `<Hyperlink` is right after the closing TAG of `</Paragraph>` then capture the string with whole `Hyperlink` value and replace it with surrounding `<Paragraph>` TAGs.

And the finished string should be like this, although I can replace the matched string with the use of `Linq`:

```
</Paragraph> some words here (@somevaluehere1)
                <Paragraph><Hyperlink NavigateUri="https://somelink.com">July 14, 2017</Hyperlink></Paragraph>
```

I want to know if it's possible to sort out this problem with `Regex` or do I need any other method.

I have made up a `Regex` pattern but I know it's not the right answer. Maybe someone with a little experience might help here.

The pattern I came up with is: `<\/Paragraph>(\s?)(\w+\s?\w+\s?)(\(?\@?\w+\)?)(\s?<Hyperlink)`

Comment: Instead of abusing regex, you could [use Linq to replace a node in an XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302711(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: Why do so many people try to use Regex to parse XML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: `(<\/Paragraph>.*\s*)(<Hyperlink.*)` and then replace by `$1<Paragraph>$2</Paragraph>`.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/VfeTDd/3

Comment: You need to close it too (the Paragraph)

Comment: Sorry. Edited it.

Comment: If there is an opening <Paragraph> TAG between the `Hyperlink` and closing TAG of `Paragraph` it still matches.

Comment: Actually I solved it, I wrapped my whole string with `Paragraph` TAGs. Thanks

Comment: If you want to ignore the word '<Paragraph>' then you can work with a negative lookahead: `(?!.*<Paragraph>)(<\/Paragraph>.*\s*)(<Hyperlink.*)` https://regex101.com/r/VfeTDd/4